# Заннулить (присвоить null) объект Java

Tags: java, ооп, объекты, null

застрял на какой-то странной проблеме, даже абсурдной.
Создаю бинарное дерево, вопрос в зануллении объекта.
[image]

Имею в методе удаления элемента дерева (public boolean remove(Object o) локальную перменную entry, которая ссылается на поле класса root - самый верхний объект, то есть 0.
Когда прописываю entry = null, объект элемента не становится null, допустим, элемент 3, он продолжает жить.
Не могу понять, почему это происходит, когда ссылка 3-ого элемента уходит именно в иерархию ссылок root.
Естественно, если я обращаюсь через поле к элементу 7 и 8, то они становятся null.

Внутри класса CustomTree:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof String)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    Entry<String> entry = root;
    Entry<String> parent;

    Queue<Entry<String>> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    String s = String.valueOf(o);
    boolean isDeletedElement = false;

    queue.add(entry);
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        entry = queue.poll();
        if(entry.getElementName().equals(s)) {
            while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
                queue.remove();
            }
            isDeletedElement = true;
        }
        if(!entry.isAvailableToAddChildren()){
            queue.add(entry.leftChild);
            queue.add(entry.rightChild);
        }
        if(isDeletedElement) {
            entry.leftChild = null;
            entry.rightChild = null;
            // entry = null;      В ИЕРАРХИИ root ОН НЕ null
        }
    }
    return isDeletedElement;
}
```

Сам Entry вложен в класс CustomTree:

```
static class Entry<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String elementName;
    boolean availableToAddLeftChildren;
    boolean availableToAddRightChildren;

    Entry<T> parent, leftChild, rightChild;

    public Entry(String elementName) {
        this.elementName = elementName;
        availableToAddLeftChildren = true;
        availableToAddRightChildren = true;
    }

    public boolean isAvailableToAddChildren() {
        return availableToAddLeftChildren || availableToAddRightChildren;
    }

    public String getElementName() {
        return elementName;
    }
}
```

В поле CustomTree объявлено Entry root;
Возможно, проблема решится, если добавить в Entry класс переменную thisEntry класса Entry, указывающая на самого себя.

Comment: Проблема, как я выразился, глупая, потому что я копирую ссылку из root, поэтому если присваиваю копии null, это не отразится на оригинальной ссылке.
Прошу уточнить или дополнить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совершенно верно, в java всё передаётся по значению, т.е. все изменения затрагивают только локальную копию. Но для объектов можно изменять состояние и эти изменения будут видны вне метода.